# Show $x^n \geq x_1^n+x_2^n+\ldots+x_k^n \Bigg\vert x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k = x, x \geq 0, n \geq 1, k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, exponentiation

Hello StackExchange Community,

This is my first post on the forum. Please forgive me for any errors with formatting and my expressions. I am working on the following proof:

Show $$x^n \geq x_1^n+x_2^n+\ldots+x_k^n \Bigg\vert x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k = x, x \geq 0, n \geq 1, k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

This is to say, I'd like to show that a positive number raised to $n\geq1$ is greater than the sum of any set of addends each raised to $n$.

*What I have scribbled so far:*

> Let's look at $x^n \geq (\frac{x}{2})^n+(\frac{x}{2})^n$
>
> $x^n \geq2 \frac{x^n}{2^n}$
>
> $x^n \geq 0$
>
> $1 \geq \frac{2}{2^n}$
>
> $2^n \geq 2$
>
> $n \geq 1$, thus true.
>
> It is obvious that $x^n \geq k(\frac{x^n}{k^n})$ is also true (for $k$
>   $x_k$ that are all equal).
>
> Can I make $x_1^n+x_2^n+\ldots+x_k^n$ look like $k(\frac{x}{k})^n$?
>   Well if $x_1^n+x_2^n+\ldots+x_k^n < k(\frac{x}{k})^n$, then it is also
>   less than $x^n$ (proving original problem).
>
> $k \geq 0$
>
> $\frac{k^n}{k}(x_1^n+x_2^n+\ldots+x_k^n) < x^n$
>
> I feel I need to use the information $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k = x$
>
> $\frac{k^n}{k}(x_1^n+x_2^n+\ldots+x_k^n) < (x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k)^n$

I am not sure how to revise my thoughts and continue. I greatly appreciate any comments and questions; thank you in advance for posting! :)

With regards,

Polite Master

Comment: Thank you for your kindness, Mann!

Comment: Note that if you can prove this for $k=2$, you can easily extend to arbitrary $k$.

Comment: The statement as written is false: take, for instance, $n=k=2, x_1=1, x_2=-1$. Did you just forget to say that each $x_i$ is $\ge 0$?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your idea won't lead to a solution, because evenly distributing will give the least possible sum. Notice that the single $n$-th power is in fact still a sum of $k\ $ $n$-th powers of numbers that have the same sum, and so essentially the problem is about maximizing the sum of the $n$-th powers given the sum of $k$ non-negative numbers. One simple approach would be to see that if you can prove that $a^n + b^n \le (a+b)^n$ for any non-negative real $a,b$, then then you can use it $(k-1)$ times to prove the result. Do you see it?

Comment: Thank you, User21820. You explained my original thoughts exactly! My last line, without the $\frac{k^n}{k}$, is similar in form to $a^n+b^n\leq(a+b)^n$, but I wasn't sure how deal with it recursively. Now that you mentioned k-1 times, I seem to recall an approach in some problem where I subtracted out a large number of terms in a sequence. I will continue to think on your comment and try remember (I am new to LaTeX, so please forgive the late response.)

Comment: If you can prove $a^n + b^n \le (a+b)^n$, surely you can prove $a^n + b^n + c^n \le (a+b+c)^n$? And then by induction the original problem is solved.

Comment: @PoliteMaster: And don't worry about late response. We get notified of comments on our own questions and answers or if a comment contains `@<username>` somewhere in it.

Comment: @PoliteMaster: In my answer I assumed you already know how to prove $a^n+b^n \le (a+b)^n$ for non-negative $a,b$ and natural $n$, which goes by a simple induction. You do not need to use Nilan's approach to prove it, and moreover his method is invalid when $a = b = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Take any rear number  $0\le y\le1.$ Then $$1=(y+(1-y))^n\ge y^n+(1-y)^n$$ is true for any $n\in\mathbb{N}.$
Take any $x_1,x_2\ge 0$ and put $y=\dfrac{x_1}{x_1+x_2}$ $$\implies(x_1+x_2)^n\ge x_1^n+x_2^n$$ Now induct on $k.$

Comment: Hi Nilan! :) I am carefully reading your answer, as it seems related to the first by User21820 and Tom-Tom's comment. I apologize for it taking me so long to process (I am not ignoring you!).

Comment: I am currently trying to understand why the domain of $x$ changes from $0 \leq x \leq 1$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It is okay if $x_k\geq0$. I am still unsure about the domain of $x$, but am currently trying to understand how $(a+b)^n \geq a^n+b^n$ is generated. Thank you again for commenting. :)

Comment: For dear down voter: Thanks for your down vote. Even without a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that $(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k)^n \ge x_1^n+x_2^n+\cdots+x_k^n$ whenever each $x_i$ is $\ge 0$. But this is obvious if you expand the left-hand side: you will get all the terms $x_1^n,x_2^n,\ldots,x_k^n$ plus some non-negative terms.

With this in mind, you should be able to prove the proposition more formally, using induction on $k$.